# Python os.walk for second level directories

Tags: python

I'm trying to print a list of second level directories from a storage drive.
Folder hierarchy is

E:

- A

  - A1
  - A2
- B

  - B1
  - B2
- C

  - C1
  - C2
    etc etc

```
dirname = "E:\\"

def walk_method(dirname):
    subfolders = [i for i in next(os.walk(dirname))[1]]
    for dir in list(subfolders):
        second_level = [next(os.walk(dirname+dir))[1]]
    
    print(second_level)


print(walk_method(dirname))
```

However I'm only getting back the results of the subdirectories from the last folder (C for example) in the list - what am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to put `print(second_level)` *inside* the for-loop, otherwise it will only see the last value. Also, `dirname+dir` cannot be right: you need to use `os.path.join(dirname, dir)`.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `os.walk` is to traverse an entire directory tree. If you only care about entries in one directory, you are needlessly traversing and fetching information about all the files in all the subdirectories, which can be a quite heavy and time-consuming operation if the tree is large.

Try this instead:

```
import os

for entry in os.scandir("E:\\"):
    entry_path = os.path.join("E:", entry)
    if os.path.isdir(entry_path):
        print(entry)
```

This should print the second level `A`, `B`, `C` in your example. If you want to access the third level `A/A1`, `A/A2`, `B/B1`, etc, add one more loop to traverse each directory you find.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into this in more detail - fortunately os.walk is fast enough to parse 8K directories in a few seconds so works for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

#### TLDR:

```py
    for dir in list(subfolders):
        second_level = [next(os.walk(dirname+dir))[1]]
    
    print(second_level)
```

This will only print `second_level` once because it's not inside the loop. Hit that `print(second_level)` with a tab and you should be alright if the code inside is working.

#### Longer Answer

[docs.python.org](https://For%20each%20directory%20in%20the%20tree%20rooted%20at%20directory%20top%20(including%20top%20itself),%20it%20yields%20a%203-tuple%20(dirpath,%20dirnames,%20filenames).%20%20dirpath%20is%20a%20string,%20the%20path%20to%20the%20directory.%20dirnames%20is%20a%20list%20of%20the%20names%20of%20the%20subdirectories%20in%20dirpath%20(excluding%20%27.%27%20and%20%27..%27).)

> "For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, ***dirnames***, filenames)...dirpath is a string, the path to the directory. ***dirnames is a list of the names of the subdirectories in dirpath*** (excluding '.' and '..').

- I might first walk your parent directory:

```py
import os
dirname = "E:\\"

dirs = list(os.walk(dirname))

parent_dir = dirs[0][0]

second_level = dirs[0][1]
# Outputs -> ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

- use `os.path.join` to make directory strings

```py
second_level_paths = [os.path.join(parent_dir, dir_) 
                        for dir_ in second_level]

print(second_level_paths)
# Outputs -->
    # ['parent_dir/a', 
    # 'parent_dir/b', 
    # 'parent_dir/c', ]
```

- then walk through each of those directories or whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: Better hit it with 4 spaces.

Comment: This is still incredibly expensive if the tree is large. Better then to refactor to avoid `os.walk` and only visit directories you care about.

Answer (score 0):

> However I'm only getting back the results of the subdirectories from the last folder (C for example) in the list - what am doing wrong?

To answer your question on why this is happening:

For every iteration through a subfolder, you are redefining `second_level` so it basically keeps replacing it’s contents, over and over again.

To fix it, you can just define a list outside of the loop, before you begin iterating through each subfolder, then add each second level, to the second_level list.

for example:

```
dirname = "E:\\"

def walk_method(dirname):
    subfolders = [i for i in next(os.walk(dirname))[1]]
    second_level = []
    for dir in list(subfolders):
        dir = [next(os.walk(dirname+dir))[1]]
        second_level.append(dir)
    
    print(second_level)


print(walk_method(dirname))
```

Comment: Thanks, this one has worked for me, and while may not be the most performative of all of the recommendations it's fast enough to process 8K directories in a few seconds - so fine for me, thanks for your help. I should have spotted the loop nesting error...

Answer (score -1):

Just do:

```
import os
dir = os.listdir() # you can pass a path, empty call will be use the current working directory

for element in dir:
    # this will print all directories in the given path (dir)
    if os.path.isdir(element):
        print(element)
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but this requires you to `cd` to the directory, or add `os.path.join` to add the full path to each entry before calling `os.path.isdir`. Also, `scandir` is quite a lot faster, at the expense of unsorted output.